# Liskov substitution design principle cannot be achieved?

Tags: solid-principles

Please give me example where "Liskov substitution" design principle cannot be achieved?

Thanks.

Comment: It would be helpful if you could expand on the context of your question — Do you mean an example of "bad code" that breaks LSP (i.e. a simple example to demonstrate why the principle is useful), or are you looking for a real-world scenario where it's difficult to implement LSP?

Answer (score 1):

A scenario where the LSP conceivably could not be achieved is where you might have two requirements for a Class A: (1) that it inherit from Class B or implement Interface C and (2) that it **not** provide some of the behaviour provided by Class B or to which Interface C contracts it.

An example of a class that violates the Liskov Substitution Principle can be found in the .NET Framework's [`ReadOnlyCollection<T>`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13819058/readonlycollection-vs-liskov-how-to-correctly-model-immutable-representations) which implements `ICollection<T>` but does not provide the required behaviour of `Add` or `Remove`. Clearly, it would not make sense for `ReadOnlyCollection<T>` to permit records to be added or removed but I suspect that there were also compelling reasons for it to implement `ICollection<T>`.

Answer (score 0):

Suggest you read up on the [circle eclipse problem](http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circle-ellipse_problem).

Basically LSP is tricky to enforce when you add additional conditions to sub types.

In the case of the circle it is an extra condition that width must equal height but the system, that only knows about the superclass eclipse, expects to be able to modify them independently.

Note this is not an issue if the eclipse has no setters on width or height. As the system using the eclipse can't modify them the circle doesn't alter the eclipse contract.